# Object Selection with Photoshop scripting

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop

I need to be able to auto select humans in a big number of images. I know their coordinates, width and height, but would ideally prefer to have a more humanoid selection, and it seems to work great via normal object selection via the interface. Now I am wondering if I can do it with Photoshop scripting? Any clues appreciated!

To clarify I'm talking about the Object Selection Tool introduced recently [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/making-quick-selections.html).

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This will require tons of backend code and quite possibly a few machine learning/AI algorithms. Very difficult to do frontend, but not _impossible_. Your best luck is to search for some sort of API that does it for you and returns a result.

Comment: ah I mean just to trigger the object selection tool? I already have the humans selected out, albeit in a rectangular bounding box. So I was wondering if I can just trigger the object selection tool using the same coordinates?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to help with this one - I just don't have enough experience here.

Comment: no problem! I still appreciate your comments. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working. In case anyone is interested:

Assuming the coordinates of the bounding box (top, left, bottom, right) are found.

```
var idset = stringIDToTypeID( "set" );
var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = stringIDToTypeID( "null" );

var ref3 = new ActionReference();
var idchannel = stringIDToTypeID( "channel" );
var idselection = stringIDToTypeID( "selection" );
ref3.putProperty( idchannel, idselection );
desc4.putReference( idnull, ref3 );

var idto = stringIDToTypeID( "to" );
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idtop = stringIDToTypeID( "top" );
    var idpixelsUnit = stringIDToTypeID( "pixelsUnit" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idtop, idpixelsUnit, top );
    var idleft = stringIDToTypeID( "left" );
    var idpixelsUnit = stringIDToTypeID( "pixelsUnit" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idleft, idpixelsUnit, left );
    var idbottom = stringIDToTypeID( "bottom" );
    var idpixelsUnit = stringIDToTypeID( "pixelsUnit" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idbottom, idpixelsUnit, bottom );
    var idright = stringIDToTypeID( "right" );
    var idpixelsUnit = stringIDToTypeID( "pixelsUnit" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idright, idpixelsUnit, right );
    
var idrectangle = stringIDToTypeID( "rectangle" );
desc4.putObject( idto, idrectangle, desc5 );
var iddeepSelect = stringIDToTypeID( "deepSelect" );
desc4.putBoolean( iddeepSelect, true );
var idobjectSelectionMode = stringIDToTypeID( "objectSelectionMode" );
desc4.putInteger( idobjectSelectionMode, 0 );
var idmagicLassoAutoEnhance = stringIDToTypeID( "magicLassoAutoEnhance" );
desc4.putBoolean( idmagicLassoAutoEnhance, true );
var idsmartSubtract = stringIDToTypeID( "smartSubtract" );
desc4.putBoolean( idsmartSubtract, true );
executeAction( idset, desc4, DialogModes.NO );
```

These codes can be obtained via the ScriptingListener (available [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html))